# Last join in query is using temporary table instead of an index

Tags: mysql

I have a query containing multiple joins. Just for this example all the values in the query are the same (key = name, value = italy).

This query contains  26 joins and with a database of about 10000 records it runs in about 12 seconds.

But when I query for up to 20 joins the query takes is dramatically faster and usually takes less than 1 second and even faster.

When checking the EXPLAIN for this query i can see that when I reach a specific number of joins the database stop using my indices and use a temporary table instead.

I know of MySQL 61 joins limit but could not find anything about this.

Here is my query and below the EXPLAIN output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id 
FROM nodes a 
       JOIN relationships c0 
         ON a.id IS NOT NULL 
            AND c0._start = a.id 
            AND c0._noderevision = a.revision 
            AND c0._type = 'author.address.state' 
       JOIN properties d0 
         ON d0._nodeid = c0._end 
            AND d0._noderevision = c0._noderevision 
            AND d0._key = 'name' 
            AND d0._value = 'italy' 
       JOIN relationships c1 
         ON a.id IS NOT NULL 
            AND c1._start = a.id 
            AND c1._noderevision = a.revision 
            AND c1._type = 'author.address.state' 
       JOIN properties d1 
         ON d1._nodeid = c1._end 
            AND d1._noderevision = c1._noderevision 
            AND d1._key = 'name' 
            AND d1._value = 'italy' 
       JOIN relationships c2 
         ON a.id IS NOT NULL 
            AND c2._start = a.id 
            AND c2._noderevision = a.revision 
            AND c2._type = 'author.address.state' 
       JOIN properties d2 
         ON d2._nodeid = c2._end 
            AND d2._noderevision = c2._noderevision 
            AND d2._key = 'name' 
            AND d2._value = 'italy' 
       JOIN relationships c3 
         ON a.id IS NOT NULL 
            AND c3._start = a.id 
            AND c3._noderevision = a.revision 
            AND c3._type = 'author.address.state' 
       JOIN properties d3 
         ON d3._nodeid = c3._end 
            AND d3._noderevision = c3._noderevision 
            AND d3._key = 'name' 
            AND d3._value = 'italy' 
       JOIN relationships c4 
         ON a.id IS NOT NULL 
            AND c4._start = a.id 
            AND c4._noderevision = a.revision 
            AND c4._type = 'author.address.state' 
       JOIN properties d4 
         ON d4._nodeid = c4._end 
            AND d4._noderevision = c4._noderevision 
            AND d4._key = 'name' 
            AND d4._value = 'italy' 
       JOIN relationships c5 
         ON a.id IS NOT NULL 
            AND c5._start = a.id 
            AND c5._noderevision = a.revision 
            AND c5._type = 'author.address.state' 
       JOIN properties d5 
         ON d5._nodeid = c5._end 
            AND d5._noderevision = c5._noderevision 
            AND d5._key = 'name' 
            AND d5._value = 'italy' 
       JOIN relationships c6 
         ON a.id IS NOT NULL 
            AND c6._start = a.id 
            AND c6._noderevision = a.revision 
            AND c6._type = 'author.address.state' 
       JOIN properties d6 
         ON d6._nodeid = c6._end 
            AND d6._noderevision = c6._noderevision 
            AND d6._key = 'name' 
            AND d6._value = 'italy' 
       JOIN relationships c7 
         ON a.id IS NOT NULL 
            AND c7._start = a.id 
            AND c7._noderevision = a.revision 
            AND c7._type = 'author.address.state' 
       JOIN properties d7 
         ON d7._nodeid = c7._end 
            AND d7._noderevision = c7._noderevision 
            AND d7._key = 'name' 
            AND d7._value = 'italy' 
       JOIN relationships c8 
         ON a.id IS NOT NULL 
            AND c8._start = a.id 
            AND c8._noderevision = a.revision 
            AND c8._type = 'author.address.state' 
       JOIN properties d8 
         ON d8._nodeid = c8._end 
            AND d8._noderevision = c8._noderevision 
            AND d8._key = 'name' 
            AND d8._value = 'italy' 
       JOIN relationships c9 
         ON a.id IS NOT NULL 
            AND c9._start = a.id 
            AND c9._noderevision = a.revision 
            AND c9._type = 'author.address.state' 
       JOIN properties d9 
         ON d9._nodeid = c9._end 
            AND d9._noderevision = c9._noderevision 
            AND d9._key = 'name' 
            AND d9._value = 'italy' 
       JOIN relationships c10 
         ON a.id IS NOT NULL 
            AND c10._start = a.id 
            AND c10._noderevision = a.revision 
            AND c10._type = 'author.address.state' 
       JOIN properties d10 
         ON d10._nodeid = c10._end 
            AND d10._noderevision = c10._noderevision 
            AND d10._key = 'name' 
            AND d10._value = 'italy' 
       JOIN relationships c11 
         ON a.id IS NOT NULL 
            AND c11._start = a.id 
            AND c11._noderevision = a.revision 
            AND c11._type = 'author.address.state' 
       JOIN properties d11 
         ON d11._nodeid = c11._end 
            AND d11._noderevision = c11._noderevision 
            AND d11._key = 'name' 
            AND d11._value = 'italy' 
       JOIN relationships c12 
         ON a.id IS NOT NULL 
            AND c12._start = a.id 
            AND c12._noderevision = a.revision 
            AND c12._type = 'author.address.state' 
       JOIN properties d12 
         ON d12._nodeid = c12._end 
            AND d12._noderevision = c12._noderevision 
            AND d12._key = 'name' 
            AND d12._value = 'italy'
```

And the EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  a   index   id_UNIQUE,revision  revision    138 NULL    214 "Using where; Using index; Using temporary"
1   SIMPLE  c0  ref fk1_idx,fk3_idx,index1  index1  142 graph.a.revision,graph.a.id 1   "Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  c1  ref fk1_idx,fk3_idx,index1  index1  142 graph.a.revision,graph.a.id 1   "Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  c2  ref fk1_idx,fk3_idx,index1  index1  142 graph.a.revision,graph.a.id 1   "Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  c3  ref fk1_idx,fk3_idx,index1  index1  142 graph.a.revision,graph.a.id 1   "Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  c4  ref fk1_idx,fk3_idx,index1  index1  142 graph.a.revision,graph.a.id 1   "Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  c5  ref fk1_idx,fk3_idx,index1  index1  142 graph.a.revision,graph.a.id 1   "Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  c6  ref fk1_idx,fk3_idx,index1  index1  142 graph.a.revision,graph.a.id 1   "Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  c7  ref fk1_idx,fk3_idx,index1  index1  142 graph.a.revision,graph.a.id 1   "Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  c8  ref fk1_idx,fk3_idx,index1  index1  142 graph.a.revision,graph.a.id 1   "Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  c9  ref fk1_idx,fk3_idx,index1  index1  142 graph.a.revision,graph.a.id 1   "Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  d0  ref fk2_idx,index1  index1  240 graph.c0._end,graph.a.revision,const    1   "Using index condition; Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  d1  ref fk2_idx,index1  index1  240 graph.c1._end,graph.a.revision,const    1   "Using index condition; Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  d2  ref fk2_idx,index1  index1  240 graph.c2._end,graph.a.revision,const    1   "Using index condition; Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  d3  ref fk2_idx,index1  index1  240 graph.c3._end,graph.a.revision,const    1   "Using index condition; Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  d4  ref fk2_idx,index1  index1  240 graph.c4._end,graph.a.revision,const    1   "Using index condition; Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  d5  ref fk2_idx,index1  index1  240 graph.c5._end,graph.a.revision,const    1   "Using index condition; Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  d6  ref fk2_idx,index1  index1  240 graph.c6._end,graph.a.revision,const    1   "Using index condition; Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  d7  ref fk2_idx,index1  index1  240 graph.c7._end,graph.a.revision,const    1   "Using index condition; Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  d8  ref fk2_idx,index1  index1  240 graph.c8._end,graph.a.revision,const    1   "Using index condition; Using where; Distinct"
1   SIMPLE  d9  ref fk2_idx,index1  index1  240 graph.c9._end,graph.a.revision,const    1   "Using index condition; Using where; Distinct"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what is happening is that you are joining data which causes it to pull back 0 records, hence why its suddenly a lot faster.

What i would do would be to slowly add one join at a time and when it pulls back 0 data then switch that join with another join you know works, if that returns 0 rows then you know its that join which is messing things up!